# SQL escape incoming data from SQL table for insertion

Tags: php, mysql

**Long Drawn Out Back-Story**

I have a collection of php/json scripts that hand out a list of commands to duplicate a database/table structure as well as access data within those databases- quite straightforward. The goal is to create an API to cache data for the many, sometimes structurally changing, databases we need access to in a mobile environment. Things like static categories with very few records are better stored in a local sqlite db than in one of the remote servers. (Generally the server side is MySQL and the local is SQLite)

Well the next step is to duplicate the data, it's quite simple to use the existing data query json api to grab that data, but the data will need to be accessible by quite a number of platforms and it would be nice to simply create the insert statements server-side. However I'm not sure of the best way to escape that data.

**Questions**

I'm planning on simply using php's `mysql_real_escape_string()` function to escape the incoming data, but is there a command in MySQL to return already escaped values from a select statement?

Is there a more mature method of importing structure and data from a remote database to a local database through a web api for caching as well as persistent storage?

Comment: Use prepared statements and update your driver to `mysqli` or `pdo`.

Comment: no, there isn't an escape function in mysql's sql dialect. that's a meta-function. and it'd be  POINTLESS for you to be using mysql's escape function, if this data is destined for OTHER databases. other dbs may/will have OTHER escaping methods. e.g. mysql uses `\'`, mssql uses `''`.

Comment: I think prepared statements are great, in this case perhaps your suggestion could be implemented with a simple full data `select*` and return that having the client create the insert statement? That would actually make a lot more sense than generating that on the server. @marc: fair enough